# Не могу подключить js к адаптивному слайдеру

Tags: javascript, html, css

В общем, вот код адаптивного слайдера, но никак не могу подключить `javascript`, помогите.

```js
 window.onload = function() {
    //Слайдер сантехники
    document.getElementById("slider_right").onclick = slidrerRight;
    var a = 0

    function slidrerRight() {
      var polosa = document.getElementById("items");
      a = a - 955;
      if (a < -2865) {
        a = 0
      }
      polosa.style.left = a + "px";

    }
    document.getElementById("slider_left").onclick = sliderLeft;

    function sliderLeft() {
      var polosa = document.getElementById('items');
      a = a + 955;
      if (a > 0) {
        a = -2865
      }
      polosa.style.left = a + 'px';
    }
  }

//Это JavaScript для этого слайдера, но там я вообще ничего не понимаю.

var d = document;
var wrap = d.querySelector('.wrap');
var items = d.querySelector('.items');
var itemCount = d.querySelectorAll('.item').length;
var scroller = d.querySelector('.scroller');
var pos = 0;
var transform = Modernizr.prefixed('transform');

function setTransform() {
  items.style[transform] = 'translate3d(' + (-pos *
    items.offsetWidth) + 'px,0,0)';
}

function prev() {
  pos = Math.max(pos - 1, 0);
  setTransform();
}

function next() {
  pos = Math.min(pos + 1, itemCount - 1);
  setTransform();
}
window.addEventListener('resize', setTransform);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 65%;
  margin: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  width: 30px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  /*прозрачность*/
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /**/
}

.scroller {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

.item {
  padding: 30px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 570px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<section id="galary" name="galary">
  <div class="galar">
    <span>Галерея наших работ</span>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="slider">
      <button onclick="prev()">&laquo;</button>
      <div class="scroller">
        <ul class="items">
          <li class="item" style="background-image: url(туалет.jpg)"></li>
          <li class="item" style="background-image: url(раковина.jpg)"></li>
          <li class="item" style="background-image: url(душ.jpg)"></li>
          <li class="item" style="background-image: url(ванна.jpg)"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button onclick="next()">&raquo;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Что значит "подключить javascript"? Вам просто какой-нибудь javascript подключить или вы какую-то конкретную задачу хотите решить тем, что подключаете?

Comment: у меня, сайт визитка так сказать и там у меня слайдер, я смог сделать его адаптивным но кнопки подключить вообще не знаю как

Comment: Так вам css не удаётся подключить или javascript. Какие такие кнопки не подключаются и какой плагин использовали, явно же не сами слайдер писали? :-D

Comment: Помоему он вообще не имеет предствления, что такое HTML CSS & JS

Comment: да слайдер писал не сам, я css подключил, я не знаю как мне через js подключить кнопки, чтоб слайдер листался

Comment: да уж мощно мне помогли

Comment: Вставьте текст css не картинкой а текстом. И не надо негативить "плохо вы мне помогли": вы пока на том уровне, что не можете ни текст вставить и путаетесь в терминах, помогать такому нулёвому уровню заочно по интернету непросто. Вы представьте себе, что просите помочь провести операцию на сердце заочно по скайпу - а сами не знаете даже как скальпель держать. Если думаете, что обвинять в такой ситуации поможет - так это зря. Вам тупо наставят минусов в репутацию за неконструктивное поведение и не будут отвечать на ваш вопрос.

Comment: я пытался он все время говорит про какие-то 4 отступа

Comment: Вставьте как угодно - я отредактирую форматирование

Comment: Никто ни на кого не гонит, я думаю, что вам тоже было бы неприятно читать, что ты ничего не понимаешь и не знаешь, хотя попросил помощи а тебя унижают

Comment: Будем вставлять код CSS ? Вас никто не упрекал - просто констатировали факт. Различайте, где идёт оценочное суждение с переходом на личности, а где просто нейтрально сообщают "вот новичок пришёл". Вы кстати, таки умеете отличаеть javascript от css?

Comment: Так, код css вижу. Теперь о самом вопросе. Что именно хотите сделать? Впишите в вопрос подробности: это самописный слайдер или готовый? (Если готовый - то название)

Comment: да конечно, я прекрасно понимаю чем отличаются css от java, вот только закончил учиться пол года на web дизайнера

Comment: мне нужно подключить javascript чтоб при нажатии на кнопки картинки менялись

Comment: Вы учили javascript? Разбирались как работают слайдеры? Вот [например статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/319394/) - попробуйте прочитать, понять механику и сделать по аналогии.

Comment: да я один раз делала слайдер, вот только я не могу тогда сделать его адаптивным, либо могу сделать адаптивным, но не могу кнопки подключить

Comment: впишите код javacript, который вы вставляли для неадаптивной версии слайдера, возможно, его удастся адаптировать для этого случая. По идее, javascript'у без разницы, какой у вас слайдер - адаптивный или нет.

Comment: Только этот java не подойдет, потому что там даже код html другой, для этого кода Html тоже есть java код только он не работает

Comment: @Максим, Java это совсем **НЕ** JavaScript

Comment: Это я запомню на всю жизнь

Answer (score 1):

Код для слайдера хорошо работает. Главное вставить его перед закрывающим тегом body, чтобы все используемые элементы уже были доступны.

Небольшая неточность будет с расчетом того, на сколько надо будет сдвинуть текущий слайд.

Расчет следующий:

```
items.style[transform] = 'translate3d(' + (-pos * items.offsetWidth) + 'px,0,0)';
```

то есть, список слайдов сдвигается на ширину просмотренных слайдов, это будет работать корректно, только если между слайдами не будет пустого места, иначе надо будет корректировать расчеты.

Плюс, в примере используется библиотека [`Modernizr`](https://modernizr.com/), которая в данном случае нужна для получения имени свойства стиля для `transform`.

Вместо него можно просто использовать строку `'transform'`.

Пример:

```js
var d = document;
var wrap = d.querySelector('.wrap');
var items = d.querySelector('.items');
var itemCount = d.querySelectorAll('.item').length;
var scroller = d.querySelector('.scroller');
var pos = 0;
// var transform = Modernizr.prefixed('transform');

function setTransform() {
  items.style['transform'] = 'translate3d(' + (-pos *
    (items.offsetWidth + 3)) + 'px,0,0)';
}

function prev() {
  pos = Math.max(pos - 1, 0);
  setTransform();
}

function next() {
  pos = Math.min(pos + 1, itemCount - 1);
  setTransform();
}
window.addEventListener('resize', setTransform);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 65%;
  margin: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  width: 30px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  /*прозрачность*/
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /**/
}

.scroller {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 570px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<section id="galary" name="galary">
  <div class="galar">
    <span>Галерея наших работ</span>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="slider">
      <button onclick="prev()">&laquo;</button>
      <div class="scroller">
        <ul class="items">
          <li class="item" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/css-3.svg')"></li>
          <li class="item" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/css-3.svg')"></li>
          <li class="item" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/css-3.svg')"></li>
          <li class="item" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/css-3.svg')"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button onclick="next()">&raquo;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромнейшее, очень хороший сайт и люди, спасибо еще раз. Есть еще такой вопрос, а как сделать так, чтобы когда долистываешь до конца нажав кнопку еще раз возвращаешься к первому

Comment: И можно ли как-то сделать так , когда я уменьшаю страницу, чтобы картинки уменьшались и по высоте тоже, а то все такое тонкое

Comment: @Максим, _нажав кнопку еще раз возвращаешься к первому_ - для этого добавь условие в функции prev и next. `pos` - это номер текущего слайда, `itemCount` - это сколько всего слайдов. Определяешь что показывается последний слайд и присваиваешь переменной `pos` значение 0

Comment: @Максим, _когда я уменьшаю страницу, чтобы картинки уменьшались и по высоте тоже_ - здесь смотри что у тебя в css. Сейчас у тебя высота у `.item` жестко задана - 570px.

Comment: в css это я менял, но если я ставлю к примеру height;auto то пропадает слайдер

Comment: @Максим, слайдер не пропадает, просто так как в нем нет элементов, он схлопывается когда установлено height;auto